# Hide empty space in ul after li was dragged

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

sorry for my english :) I search an answer for a long time, but i think i do wrong reqewest.

So, i have a "ul" list with draggable "li" elements. And i can drag it to div elemen.
When i dragging it into droppable place, my "li" list have an empty places. The style of dragging li is chahging.After dropping, li element change its position and it stay into droppable element and get his original style, but how can i hide its empty area in ul list?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".spisokznach").draggable({
delay:200, 
scroll: 'true',
opacity:0.80, 
cursorAt:{left:34, bottom : 15}, 
cursor:'move', 
revert:'invalid', 
snap:'.place',
appendTo:'.place',
snapMode:'inner' ,
});


$(".place").droppable({
activeClass: "placehover",
hoverClass: "placehover2",
accept:'.spisokznach',
drop: function(event, ui){
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', function(){return false});

         alert("You dropped "+$(ui.draggable).attr('id')+" into "+$(this).attr('id')+" block")
        $(ui.draggable).addClass('new'); 

    },
out: function(event, ui){
       $(ui.draggable).removeClass('new'); 
       ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', function(){
            $(this).data('draggable').originalPosition = {
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            };

            return true;
        });
    },

})
});
```

I want to have something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/sgZE2/
After dragging an element, empty space is hiding, and the list become closer.

Comment: +1 for your question, I reckon all you need is the revert prperty as your draggable is not controlled - see this demo; http://jsfiddle.net/vQjLw/ lemme know if it fit your need - I will set this as answer! take it easy! `:)`

Comment: tnx,but need the element be visible in there new place. So i think i need to clone my dragged element into droppable element and then i will hide this origanal element, as a result, my menu will decrease in size, but user still can the the element he dropped